# Ruby Nginx config parser

Tags: ruby, nginx

I need a Ruby-based Nginx config parser that can:

- Parse an Nginx config file
- Error out on any syntax errors

I want to use this in a CI/CD pipeline as a simple way of detecting syntax errors without having to actually spin up a VM or Docker container and then run `nginx -t`.

I looked at this one for instance ([ref](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nginx_config_parser/1.0.0)) and a few others, but they all suffer the same problem that they don't raise errors when the syntax is invalid.

Does anyone know of any code that does this? If not, could anyone recommend the best project to use as a starting point in order to write my own.

Comment: nginx config is very custom and could change in the future. Instead of porting the config, it's probably easier to try building a native extension from the official code base (config module looks like this https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/core/ngx_conf_file.c)

Comment: Honestly, I think using something like a docker container is your best option. The configuration validity will vary depending on nginx version, for example. If speed is the issue, you could run this check in parallel to others, in a separate process?

Comment: Yeah well only problem with that is I would need to spin up about 2000 docker containers, and also set up all the nginx configs in their appropriate places, whereas if I had the nginx parser I could find all errors in less than a minute.